# Create multi-process with specified number of childs using fork()

Tags: c, multiprocessing, fork

I would like to make a program that has several numbers as input and each number (separated by space) has to be treated in 4 different process to see if it's a prime number. In the case it is, a counter has to be added (so the child must have a shared memory I'm thinking).

Once my process is done with one number, it gets another one that isn't being treated by other process. The idea is for them to work almost in parallel.

What I am thinking of doing is separate the string in tokens and send it to the child process.

Here's what I've done so far:

```
unsigned int i = 0;
int processes = 4;
char *s=malloc(sizeof(char)*100);

fgets (s, 100, stdin);

for (i = 0; i < processes; ++i) {
    if (fork() == 0) {
        printf("Process %d:", i);
        make_token(s);
        treat_number(token);
        exit(0);
    }
}
// wait all child processes
int status;
for (i = 0; i < processes; ++i)
wait(&status);

return 0;
```

But with that my program ends after process 4 is done and they aren't exactly working in parallel.

So how can I make it treat several numbers in 4 processes almost at the same time with each getting a different number until my string ends?

An exemple of input/output would be:

```
Input: 0 10 100000000 100007701 100015739 3 5
Output: 4
```

Comment: *Once my process is done with one number, it gets another one that isn't being treated by other process. The idea is for them to work almost in parallel.* Unless I am missing something, this requires a lot of work. You have to establish communication lines between the parent process and the child process so the child process can inform the parent when it is done.

Comment: and then... You have to put the child process in a waiting loop to receive the next set of instructions from the parent. You have to put the parent process in a loop to receive notification from the child process when they are done processing the instructions.

Comment: once a child is done processing do you want the child process to wait for the next number or you don't care and you will just spawn a new child?

Comment: Isn't there a way to fork for each number, then when the process counter reaches 4, it kills all child and start forking again until the string ends? I think the idea would be to work with the same 4 processes but anything that makes my program work would be a good setting point. Even if the child wait for the other since the processing time is very fast..

Comment: @RSahu using mmap the father can communicate to the child but child can't communicate with each other.. Do you know a way to make a full communication?

Comment: Why would you want to "kill" the child? why not have the child exit once it's done processing? You won't even have to "communicate" with the parent, simply have the child exit with a status and if the status exists add to the counter

Comment: @AhmedMasud how can I make it exit with a status? I don't want to kill the child, if it's possible I would like to keep the same 4 child but as R Sahu said that may be difficult to make it wait. So killing the child and forking another could be an idea, but a bad one. Bottom line: I can only have 4 processes running and they can't treat the same number/token

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient way, but you at least it eliminates the need to communicate with the children:

- Make all processes know all numbers, perhaps by just letting them know the complete input, as the code already does.
- Make each process aware which child it is. Currently done by the value of `i`.
- Let each process take care of the `number-of-processes`<sup>th</sup> number from the input.

  Assuming 4 processes then for `i == 3` this would be the 3rd, 7th, 11th ... number from the input, for `i == 1` it would be 1st, 5th, 9th, ...